# Windows 2003 Server - Can I map a folder to another folder on the same server?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Scenario:

I have a server that was running low on space.  We have an external iscsi SAN that it now has a LUN on and connected to the server as E:\

We are moving the PHOTOS folder from the old location on D:\ to the new E:.  That new drive is being shared out as "ARCHIVE".

So:

`\\server\shared\photos` now becomes `\\server\archive\photos`

I can easily place a shortcut in the original location saying "DOUBLE CLICK HERE FOR THE PHOTOS", but it isn't ideal.

What I'd like is to be able to have `\\server\shared\photos` simply point to `\\server\archive\photos`.  So that if someone wants to map a drive to `\\server\shared` and then browse to the photos folder once in there they will see what is in the `\\server\archive\photos` location.

Is that possible?  I was thinking about SUBST or DFS, but I don't think either of those will do it.

Comment: sounds like you want symlinks for Windows :)

Comment: DFS will do what you want. And it's more maintainable than creating a "hardlink" junction point. Deploying DFS isn't the easiest however, and would require a bit of though. I use if for instances like this all the time however; people never have any idea that the files are scattered across different servers, or different drives on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a NTFS mount point (sometimes called "junction point"); it's quite difficult to find documentation about them, but they've been around since Windows 2000.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205524/en-us

To mount a drive as a folder instead of giving it a drive letter:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307889/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Junction by Sysinternals -- NTFS method of creating UNIX-like hard links:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

Comment: They are closer to hardlinks than symlinks